# Extracting SVN data with Java

Tags: java, svn

Does anyone know a good Java lib that will hook into SVN so I can extract the data?  I want the SVN comments, author, path, etc...  Hopefully with this data I can build a better time management tracking system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/).  It's dual-licensed, so you have to pay only if you're doing commercial work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work with SVNKit.Its easy and flexible to use.